# Apache Flink: Wierd FlatMap behaviour

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm ingesting a stream of data into Flink. For each 'instance' of this data, I have a timestamp. I can detect if the machine I'm getting the data from is 'producing' or 'not producing', this is done via a custom flat map function that's located in it's own static class.

I want to calculate how long the machine has been producing / not producing.
My current approach is collecting the production and non production timestamps in two plain lists. For each 'instance' of the data, I calculate the current production/non-production duration by subtracting the latest timestamp from the earliest timestamp. This is giving me incorrect results, though. When the production state changes from producing to non producing, I clear the timestamp list for producing and vice versa, so that if the production starts again, the duration starts from zero.

I've looked into the two lists I collect the respective timestamps in and I see things I don't understand. My assumption is that, as long as the machine 'produces', the first timestamp in the production timestamp list stays the same, while new timestamps are added to the list per new instance of data.
Apparantly, this assumption is wrong since I get seemingly random timestamps in the lists. They are still correctly ordered, though.

Here's my code for the flatmap function:

```
public static class ImaginePaperDataConverterRich extends RichFlatMapFunction<ImaginePaperData, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4736981447434827392L;
    private transient ValueState<ProductionState> stateOfProduction;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS");
    DateFormat timeDiffFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
    String timeDiffString = "00 00:00:00.000";
    List<String> productionTimestamps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> nonProductionTimestamps = new ArrayList<>();

    public String calcProductionTime(List<String> timestamps) {
        if (!timestamps.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Date firstDate = dateFormat.parse(timestamps.get(0));
                Date lastDate = dateFormat.parse(timestamps.get(timestamps.size()-1));
                long timeDiff = lastDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();

                if (timeDiff < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Something weird happened. Maybe EOF.");
                    return timeDiffString;
                }

                timeDiffString = String.format("%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)   % TimeUnit.HOURS.toHours(1),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeDiff)  % TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("State duration: " + timeDiffString);
        }
        return timeDiffString;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        ValueStateDescriptor<ProductionState> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
            "stateOfProduction",
            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<ProductionState>() {}),
            ProductionState.NOT_PRODUCING);
            stateOfProduction = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(ImaginePaperData ImaginePaperData, Collector<String> output) throws Exception {
        List<String> warnings = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        String productionTime = "0";
        String nonProductionTime = "0";

        // Data analysis
        if (stateOfProduction == null || stateOfProduction.value() == ProductionState.NOT_PRODUCING && ImaginePaperData.actSpeedCl > 60.0) {
            stateOfProduction.update(ProductionState.PRODUCING);
        } else if (stateOfProduction.value() == ProductionState.PRODUCING && ImaginePaperData.actSpeedCl < 60.0) {
            stateOfProduction.update(ProductionState.NOT_PRODUCING);
        }

        if(stateOfProduction.value() == ProductionState.PRODUCING) {
            if (!nonProductionTimestamps.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Production has started again, non production timestamps cleared");
                nonProductionTimestamps.clear();
            }
            productionTimestamps.add(ImaginePaperData.timestamp);

            System.out.println(productionTimestamps);
            productionTime = calcProductionTime(productionTimestamps);
        } else {
            if(!productionTimestamps.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Production has stopped, production timestamps cleared");
                productionTimestamps.clear();
            }
            nonProductionTimestamps.add(ImaginePaperData.timestamp);
            warnings.add("Production has stopped.");

            System.out.println(nonProductionTimestamps);
            //System.out.println("Production stopped");
            nonProductionTime = calcProductionTime(nonProductionTimestamps);
        }
// The rest is just JSON stuff
```

Do I maybe have to hold these two timestamp lists in a ListState?

EDIT: Because another user asked, here is the data I'm getting.

```
{'szenario': 'machine01', 'timestamp': '31.10.2018 09:18:39.432069', 'data': {1: 100.0, 2: 100.0, 101: 94.0, 102: 120.0, 103: 65.0}}
```

The behaviour I expect is that my flink program collects the timestamps in the two lists productionTimestamps and nonProductionTimestamps. Then I want my calcProductionTime method to subtract the last timestamp in the list from the first timestamp, to get the duration between when I first detected the machine is "producing" / "not-producing" and the time it stopped "producing" / "not-producing".

Comment: Can you give an example showcasing input records and the expected behavior?

Comment: @shriyog I made an edit, does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason for the 'seemingly random' timestamps is Apache Flink's parallel execution. When the parallelism is set to > 1, the order of events isn't guaranteed anymore.

My quick fix was to set the parallelism of my program to 1, this guarantees the order of events, as far as I know.